# Change localization in activity with another process

Tags: android, kotlin, unity-game-engine

Got Unity in Android project and have to launch this activity in another process, but localization of this activity is different from other part of application.  Any suggestions how to change locale?

Manifest declaration of activity

```
        android:name=".screens.unityScreens.UnityActivity"
        android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density"
        android:exported="false"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:process=":unityplayer"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:resizeableActivity="false"
        android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector">
```

Changing localisation in onCreate or onStart by setting Locale or using library has no result.
Library that used implementation "com.github.YarikSOffice:lingver:1.3.0"